# How to write using space and more than one line in C?

Tags: c

I want to write a text and save it in .txt using `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`. But with this way, I only could save one line, no more.

```
int main()
{
   file*pf;
   char kar;

   if ((pf = fopen("try.txt","w")) == NULL)
   {
      printf("File couldn't created!\r\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   while((kar=getchar()) != '\n')
      fputc(kar, pf);

   fclose(pf);
}
```

Comment: Note that C is a case-sensitive language.  `file *pf` is incorrect and `FILE *pf` is correct.  Also, as I pointed out in a comment to one of the answers, the return type of `getchar()` is `int`, not `char`.  It has to be able to encode any valid character and also EOF, which is distinct.  You can't do that in a `char`, so it returns `int`.  If your plain `char` is a signed type, someone typing character code 0xFF (usually ÿ, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) will be treated as typing EOF; if plain `char` is unsigned, no value will match EOF.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
char kar;

...

while((kar=getchar()) != '\n')
   fputc(kar, pf);
```

use

```
int kar;
// Use int for type of kar

...

while((kar=getchar()) != EOF )
                     //  ^^^
   fputc(kar, pf);
```

Comment: the main problem is you can not input a line break. check [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed

Comment: This would be great advice, but the conversion of `int` to `char` transforms the `EOF` to a character value... even though *`EOF` isn't a character value*.

Comment: Note that the return value from `getchar()` is an `int`, not a `char`, so storing it in a `char` will cause confusion one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

`'\n'` means end of line. Here, you are looking for end of file. So, use macro `EOF` instead of `'\n'` in your code.

Comment: Let assume that I want to input 3 lines, then how I make it stop in 3rd line?
@saurabh-agarwal

Comment: @Embek: Take your prior solution and count the number of lines, and adapt the while loop to break at != \n && numberOfLines <= 3

Comment: @Embek , Or enter CTRL+D (if you are using linux/unix/osx) or else press CTRL+Z (windows/DOS)

Comment: @ckruczek and how to use that? i don't really understand.

Comment: Well @Embek, just add a counter to your program and increment it every time a '\n' was recognized. Not too hard to manage I guess

Comment: @Embek , In that case, use ckruczek's suggestion `int counter = 0;` and then `while( counter < 3 && (kar=getchar()) != EOF) { fputc(kar, pf); if(kar == '\n') counter++;}` and make sure `kar` is an `int`, not a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Full Working Code which puts multiple line into your text file. To end the input from terminal just press `Ctrl + Z`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *pf;
   char kar;

   if ((pf = fopen("try.txt","w")) == NULL)
   {
      printf("File couldn't created!\r\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   while((kar=getchar()) != EOF)
      fputc(kar, pf);

   fclose(pf);

   return 0;
}
```